# How to download data from wikipedia in qt program?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am writing Qt program in which I can give key word of query and program first generate wikipedia link matching the query and then store data from generated link page into file.

Below is link where I can get my query matching link

```
QString wikiLink = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="
    + soName.replace(" ", "_").toLower() + "_" + soType.toLower()
    + "&format=xml&limit=1";
```

If my soName and soType are Auriga and Constellation than wikilink is as follow:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=auriga_constellation&format=xml&limit=1

Now how can I extract link of my desired article from above link page and then extract data from that article on that link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I download data from any link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309726/how-can-i-download-data-from-any-link)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with QtWebKit which allows  you to find elements in the HTML strings.

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwebkit/qwebframe.html#findFirstElement

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwebkit/qwebelement.html#attribute

Comment: That URL returns XML, not HTML.

Comment: @svick: can you please how to deal with this particular which returns xml ?